# Elementary Probability problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I think this is true, but i can't seem to prove it:

Let A,B be events in $\Omega$ and $C_i$ be a partition of $\Omega$.

$$P(A | B) = \sum_i P(A | B \cap C_i)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Q(A) = P(A \mid B)$. We know $Q$ is a probability measure.

Then, if $C_i$ is a partition, then $Q(A) = \sum Q(A \mid C_i)Q(C_i) = \sum Q(A \cap C_i)$
Remembering what $Q$ is, we get $P(A \mid B) = \sum P(A \cap C_i \mid B) = \sum P(A \cap C_i \cap B) / P(B) = \sum P(A \mid B \cap C_i)P(B \cap C_i) / P(B) =$ $$ \sum P(A \mid B \cap C_i)P(C_i \mid B)$$

But it's not true that $P(C_i \mid B) = 1$ for every $i$

Comment: Note if $B=\Omega$ then $P(C_i|B)=P(C_i)$ not $1$

Comment: @coffeemath oh right! Edited :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that for any events $E,F,$ by definition  $P(E|F)=P(E \cap F)/P(F)$ provided $P(F)>0$ to make the division possible.

Also note that for the sample space $\Omega$ the above definition gives, whenever $P(F)>0,$ that $$P(\Omega|F)=P(\Omega \cap F)/P(F)=P(F)/P(F)=1.$$

You wish to show that $$P(A | B) = \sum_i P(A | B \cap C_i). \tag{1}$$

So if your partition $C_i$ is into more than one part, and if $P(B)>0$ so the left side of $(1)$ is defined,  and if also the right side of $(1)$ is defined i.e. if each $P(B \cap C_i)>0,$ then in case we take $A=\Omega$ in your formula we will get the contradiction that $$1=1+1+\cdots+1,$$ where there is one $1$ on the right for each cell in the partition.

It isn't difficult to construct other counterexamples which don't involve using the entire sample space as one of the events.